# $\frac{1}{\det(A)}A=\operatorname{adj}(A^{-1})$ Proof Check

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, determinant

Starting with the adjoint rule $$A^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det(A)}\operatorname{adj}(A)$$
So,

> 1. $(A^{-1})^{-1}=\dfrac{1}{\det(A^{-1})}\operatorname{adj}(A^{-1})$
> 2. $A=\dfrac{1}{\det(A^{-1})}\operatorname{adj}(A^{-1})$
> 3. $\det(A^{-1})A=\operatorname{adj}(A^{-1})$
> 4. $\dfrac{1}{\det(A)}A=\operatorname{adj}(A^{-1})$

Is this method simply done by considering the adjoint rule and then replacing all $A$
's in the adjoint rule with $A^{-1}$? Technically that would be correct, no? Or is it doing something else?

Comment: It's perfect. ${}$

Comment: @Bernard I just copied the proof, I am wondering if Is this method simply done by considering the adjoint rule and then replacing all $A $'s in the adjoint rule with $A^{−1}$?

Comment: It  also uses the multiplicative property of determinants. But basically , it uses this single rule.

Comment: I In general the adjoint rule read for every matrix $$\det(A)\cdot I=A\cdot\mathrm{adj}(A).$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@Bernard** - "It also uses the multiplicative property of determinants. But basically , it uses this single rule."

Additionally,

**@Michael Hoppe** - "I In general the adjoint rule read for every matrix
$det(A)⋅I=A⋅adj(A)$"